# Xamarin Android TabLayout calling SetupWithViewPager throws exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to setup tabs like Google Play, I'm following [this guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) and converting to C#, but an exception is thrown when calling `tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager`. The code for the activity is this:

```
public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
        viewPager.Adapter = new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, this);

        var tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

The stacktrace for the exception is:

```
07-28 23:08:39.068 I/MonoDroid( 4040): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040): Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type 'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown.
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040): at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x0004b>
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x00063] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:571
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040): at Android.Support.Design.Widget.TabLayout.SetupWithViewPager (Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager) <IL 0x00066, 0x001c3>
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040): at TabTest.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00040] in E:\VS Projects\TabTest\TabTest\MainActivity.cs:28
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040): at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2707
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.1f96a184-9cb6-4d05-8516-4c4d2e85d8d7 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00027>
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040): android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:475)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:1196)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1112)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:612)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:646)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:345)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:320)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:601)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:575)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at md5be39043e4dbb7988fedb01f9386df4d7.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at md5be39043e4dbb7988fedb01f9386df4d7.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-28 23:08:39.071 I/MonoDroid( 4040):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I'm not using `<merge />` anywhere so I presume that it is internal to one of the controls? I presume that this is just an issue with Xamarin Android (or I've made a mistake somewhere) as there seems to be several very similar Java implementations that I assume work ok!

I've uploaded the full sample to [GitHub](https://github.com/ChrisWay/TabTest).

Comment: Your sample on GitHub, after changing line 36 in the PageFragment.cs to make it build in VS2013, builds and runs fine here.

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron, just tried it after wiping out the bin and obj directories and it works fine here now as well.

Comment: OK, glad to hear it worked out for you. If you need a more complete sample for the new design stuff, toolbar etc. Take a look at https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/Cheesesquare

Comment: Cheesebaron i am using the DK.Ostebaronen.Droid.ViewPagerIndicator.dll form the ViewPagerIndicator project. After Installing GCM v.26 my project crashes during mDrawer.SetDrawerShadow(Resource.Drawable.drawer_shadow,(int)GravityFlags.Start);  with the 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod' exception

Comment: Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Bit of a phantom error as after clearing the bin and obj directories it now works as expected.

Comment: THANKS for mentioning this. I was hunting down the exactly same behaviour and without your stacktrace I would have probably never found this!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. So peculiar.

Comment: Still true to this day. You saved me a lot of time thanks.

Comment: Add me to the list :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue for anther reason , this issue may be raise if you include any nested fragment dont implement onCreateview()

so if you include nested fragment inside your viewPager make sure they all implemented in correct way

hope this inspire any one face same issue